# Image from RGB to HSI to show hue image, Saturation image and Intensity image

Tags: java, image, image-processing, rgb

[Output of hue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqqVs.png)

I am trying the image from `RGB` to `HSI`  in java and then I want to show three images:
 H- hue image, S - Saturation  image, I- Intensity image

```
private void jButton_Convert_HSIActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    BufferedImage image = null;
    BufferedImage processed_hue, processed_sat, processed_in;

    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\ATH\\Desktop\\photo\\Rotate\\test_rotate_lena.png"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    processed_hue = new BufferedImage(width, height, image.getType());
    processed_sat = new BufferedImage(width, height, image.getType());
    processed_in = new BufferedImage(width, height, image.getType());

    for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) //thuc hien lap cho y chay tu o den chieu cao anh
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < height; x++) //thuc hien lap cho x chay tu 0 den chieu rong
        {
            Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
            float h = 0;
            float r, g, b, s, i, theta;

            // RGB TO HSI CONVERSION
            int red = c.getRed();
            int green = c.getGreen();
            int blue = c.getBlue();
            float total = red + green + blue;
            r = red / total;
            g = green / total;
            b = blue / total;

            System.out.println("normalize red " + r);
            System.out.println(" red = " + red + " green = " + green + " blue = " + blue);

            s = 1 - (3 * Math.min(r, Math.min(g, b)));
            i = total / (3 * 255);
            theta = (float) Math.acos((0.5 * ((r - g) + (r - b))) / Math.pow((((r - g) * (r - g)) + ((r - b) * (g - b))), 1 / 2));
            System.out.println(" theta " + theta);
            if (b <= g) {
                //  h = ((1 / Math.cos((0.5 * (2 * r - g - b)) / (Math.sqrt(((r - g) * (r - g) + (r - b) * (g - b)))))));
                h = theta;

            } else {
                h = (float) ((2 * Math.PI) - theta);
            }
            System.out.println("Intial hue = " + h + " saturation = " + s + " intensity = " + i);

            float h1 = (float) (h * (180 / Math.PI)); //to  change Radian to Degree - multiply 180/pi
            float s1 = (s * 100);
            float i1 = (i * 255);
            System.out.println(" Hue = " + Math.round(h1) + " Saturation = " + Math.round(s1) + " Intensity = " + Math.round(i1));

            // hue               


            float HSV[] = new float[3];
           // Color.RGBtoHSB(red, green, blue, HSV);
            processed_hue.setRGB(x, y, Color.getHSBColor(h1, HSV[1], HSV[2]).getRGB());

          //  processed_sat.setRGB(x, y, Color.getHSBColor(HSV[0], s1, HSV[2]).getRGB());
           // processed_in.setRGB(x, y, Color.getHSBColor(HSV[0], HSV[1], i1).getRGB());
        }
    } // end for loop

    try {
        // save images
        ImageIO.write(processed_hue, "png", new File("C:\\Users\\ATH\\Desktop\\photo\\HSI\\hue_image.png"));
        ImageIO.write(processed_sat, "png", new File("C:\\Users\\ATH\\Desktop\\photo\\HSI\\sat_image.png"));
        ImageIO.write(processed_in, "png", new File("C:\\Users\\ATH\\Desktop\\photo\\HSI\\in_image.png"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println("Image is saved in D drive: ");
    /*
     try {
     File sat_out1 = new File("C:\\Users\\ATH\\Desktop\\photo\\HSI\\sat_image.png");
     ImageIO.write(sat_image, "png", sat_out1);
     } catch (IOException ex) {
     System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
     }
     System.out.println("Image is saved in D drive: ");

     try {
     File inten_out1 = new File("C:\\Users\\ATH\\Desktop\\photo\\HSI\\inten_image.png");
     ImageIO.write(inten_image, "png", inten_out1);
     } catch (IOException ex) {
     System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
     }
     System.out.println("Image is saved in D drive: ");
     */

}
```

Please advice me and help me. How can I get H image, S image and I image?

Comment: Try making a small, non-square image with known values so you can test and debug. Use ImageMagick in the Terminal. `magick -size 3x2 xc:red RED3X2.PNG` to make a small red image, or `magick -size 256x256 gradient:blue-white GRADIENT.PNG`

Comment: I have to reduce image size. I tested image size 256*256 so I try small size image. Thanks!

Comment: I generally debug with non-square images so I can see very quickly if I am processing the wrong way or I have rotated the image. I also use solid colours and/or gradients so I know what RGB values I am expecting at each location. Good luck!

Comment: Thank Mark Setchell.